# Prolog - how do you insert an element to a list

Tags: prolog

If I have a list in Prolog such as `X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]`, how do I add the element 5 to the list to have `X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`?

Comment: Please show any attempt you've made at solving this.

Comment: does lists need to be sorted after insert operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st parameter: the "new" element

2nd parameter: Old list

3rd parameter: New list with the "new" element

```
addElement(X, [], [X]). 
addElement(X, [Y | Rest], [X,Y | Rest]) :- X @< Y, !.
addElement(X, [Y | Rest1], [Y | Rest2]) :- addElement(X, Rest1, Rest2).
```

Sample Usage:

```
?- addElement(5,[1,2,3,4,6,7], X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].

?- addElement(5,[1,2,3,4,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]).
true.

?- addElement(5,[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5]).
true .

?- addElement(5,[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5]).
false.

?- addElement(5,X, [1,2,3,5]).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
```

Comment: I'm unable to get output. addElement[5,[1,2,3,4],[6,7]).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @Priyaranjan you're going to need to clarify your original question (use edit) if you are expecting some kind of result other than `false` for the query `addElement(5, [1,2,3,4], [6,7]).`.

Answer (score 0):

SortedList will be the result you're looking for.

```
append([1,2,3,4,6,7], [5], Z), sort(Z, SortedList).
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, X is the element to be inserted at position Y.

```
addE(X,1,[G|T],[G,X|T]):-write(hello).
addE(X,Y,[H|T],[H|T1]):-Y1 is Y-1,addE(X,Y1,T,T1).


?-addE(10,3,[1,2,3,4,6,7], X).
X = [1,2,3,10,4,6,7] ?
```

Comment: And you might upgrade your explanation. As is, this is borderline code-only.